# Best way to create variable depth category?

Tags: java, design-patterns

My question regards how to best create a variable depth hierarchy. 
Let´s say that I want to be able to put a product in a category hierarchy, however the depth of the hierarchy differs for different products.

For example, a Ferrari might be in the category Vehicle -> Car -> Sports
while a LED 3D TV might be in Electronics -> TV -> LED -> 3D.

Hopefully you get the idea :-) 
What would be the best way to model this? Should I create a Category object that can hold a List of itself, with perhaps a boolean attribute telling if the current object is a leaf-node or not? Other suggestions?`

Or should I just try REALLY hard to have a fixed depth for my hierarchies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The model to represent the categories could be a tree (with an invisible root node, the "start", or whatever). Each category has one parent and one or many child categories.

Then, for the product, add a list of categories to that product. This is quite flexible because one day you may think about listing a single product in different categories.

---

Very Basic model for the category class:

```
public class Category {

  private List<Category> children = new ArrayList<Category>();
  private Category parent;
  private String name;

  // private constructor
  private Category(Category parent, String name) { 
    this.parent = parent; 
    this.name = name;
  }

  // adds a category to this category
  public Category addCategory(String name) { 
     Category child = new Category(this, name);
     children.add(child); 
     return child;
  }

  // creates and returns a new categories tree
  public static Category createCategories() {
     return new Category(null, "root");
  }
}
```

Comment: This looks a lot like what I had in mind, but couldn´t quite get down in code. I´ll go with this approach for starters at least :-) Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

There's a number of choices you could make, but I would have something like

```
class Product
{
    private Category category;
    // ...
}

class Category
{
    private Category parent;
    private String name;

    public Category getParent() { return parent; }
    public boolean isTopLevelCategory() { return parent == null }

    public String getName() { return name; }

    public String getFullName() {
       if(isTopLevelCategory())
          return name;
       else
          return parent.getFullName() + " -> " + name;
    }

    // ....
}
```

Product know their category (the most specific level - so Ferrari is in "Sports")

Categories know their parent, so "Sports" points to "Cars", "Cars" points to "Vehicles", "Vehicles" points to null, because it is a top level category.

That will also map pretty well onto an SQL database if you need to store it that way.

You'll still need to decide how to store a list of all available categories though.

Also, if you need to be able to go from a top-level category to all it's children, then you'll probably want to store those reverse links as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your suggestion with the `Category` object sounds right to me. The [composite pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) might match very well.

I also like the idea of Andreas_D to decouple the products and the category hierarchy.